# Why my Script (to change css style) doesn't work inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, bootstrap-modal, updatepanel

I have a `UpdatePanel` with de following code inside:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>

<nav class="navbar">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
   <li class="item0"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnhoje" runat="server">Hoje</a></li>
   <li class="item1"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnserie" runat="server">Série</a></li>
   <li class="item2"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnutente" runat="server">Utente</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
  <asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
...
  </asp:View>
  <asp:View ID="Tab2" runat="server">
...
  </asp:View>
  <asp:View ID="Tab3" runat="server">
...
  </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**PS:** I'm using `Bootstrap` and my `UpdatePanel` is inside a `Modal`.

And here is my `Script`:

```
<script>
  var CurrentView = <%= MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex %>;
  if (CurrentView == 0){
    $('a').closest('ul').find('.item0').addClass('active');
  }
  else if (CurrentView == 1){
    $('a').closest('ul').find('.item1').addClass('active');
  }
  else if (CurrentView == 2){
    $('a').closest('ul').find('.item2').addClass('active');
  };
</script>
```

So my problem is when I open the `Modal` the `UpdatePanel` update's and my `Script` doesn´t do anything and when I change the `View` in `Multiview` I wanted to add `class "active"` to my `li` tag but only when I click in `item0`, `item1` or `item2` and default view is `item0`.

`nav` inside `UpdatePanel`
[image]

---

`nav` outside `UpdatePanel`

[image]

If I didn't made myself clear feel free to ask me.

**EDIT:**

```
$('.teste-bar .nav li').on('click', 'body', function(){
  $('.teste-bar .nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">  
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li id="item0" class="active"><a href="#" onclick="view('MainContent_UpdatePanel4', 'MainContent_HiddenField2', '0', 'MainContent_Button1')">Hoje</a></li>
        <li id="item1"><a href="#" onclick="view('MainContent_UpdatePanel4', 'MainContent_HiddenField2', '1', 'MainContent_Button1')">Série</a></li>
        <li id="item2"><a href="#" onclick="view('MainContent_UpdatePanel4', 'MainContent_HiddenField2', '2', 'MainContent_Button1')">Utente</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="hidden" runat="server" OnClick="btnViews" />

    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
      <asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
    ...
      </asp:View>
      <asp:View ID="Tab2" runat="server">
    ...
      </asp:View>
      <asp:View ID="Tab3" runat="server">
    ...
      </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My Script:

```
<script>
    function view(servercontrolid, indexcontrolid, index, controlclick) {

        var up = document.getElementById(servercontrolid);
        var control = document.getElementById(controlclick);

        if (up) {
            document.getElementById(indexcontrolid).value = index;
            control.click();
        }

        if (index == 0) {
            $('a').closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('a').closest('nav').find('#item0').addClass('active');
        } else if (index == 1) {
            $('a').closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('a').closest('nav').find('#item1').addClass('active');
        } else if (index == 2) {
            $('a').closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $('a').closest('nav').find('#item2').addClass('active');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this please

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <nav class="navbar test-bar">  
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="item0 active"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnhoje" runat="server">Hoje</a></li>
            <li class="item1"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnserie" runat="server">Série</a></li>
            <li class="item2"><a href="#" onserverclick="btnutente" runat="server">Utente</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
    <asp:View ID="Tab1" runat="server">
    ...
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="Tab2" runat="server">
    ...
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="Tab3" runat="server">
    ...
    </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>

    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>


**JQuery**
$( function() { // Document Ready
    $('.test-bar .nav li').on('click', '.wrapper', function(){
        $('.test-bar .nav li').removeClass('active'); // Corrected Line
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's not my problem. my script work's but when i click in the item0 the UpdatePanel update and clear class "active" @Legues

Comment: Now i understood your problem. Try the code i´ve created here for you. :)

Comment: in function() it says expected ')'

Comment: doesn't do anything. what was it suposed to do?

Comment: Add class active to the clicked li element. Of course that you have to rename the .parent-update-panel class to your code... chose for example the body or other element above the updatePanel.

Comment: Can you show me the code you are trying with my code?

Comment: go my question in EDIT @Legues

Comment: God... my fault i corrected the class name. Test now with the updated code. I updated class name .test-bar on HTML markup and jquery code.

Comment: Ahh, and i added class active on your first li. ;)

Comment: but i have the classes and doesn't work i tryed with same classes

Comment: now only the first item (item0) have the class active and doesnt do anything

Comment: Have you got jquery included in your document ? If yes, try to add the code on document ready. I´ve tested the code, and it´s working

Comment: I believe this is your problem... and your solution :) - https://forums.asp.net/t/1984954.aspx?Jquery+Not+working+inside+of+update+panel

Comment: what?? don't understand

Comment: Check this fiddle that i created for you.- https://jsfiddle.net/nqp6v396/

Comment: im using a bootstrap modal to open UpdatePanel and because of that (Modal) it doesn't work. see in this link the live demo modal -
 http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals and inside of the modal insert the code. @Legues

Comment: Give me some time to search, ok? ;)

Comment: You are welcome!!! Sometimes its not so easy to figure out such a specific situation as yours!!! ;D

Comment: ok my solution shared ;) If I didn't made myself clear teel me @Legues